# Using dbContext in custom assembly for SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, entity-framework-6, ssrs-2012

I've installed the assembly into the GAC using .NET 4.6.2. My custom assembly for my SSRS project crash whenever I try to instantiate a dbContext class or inherit from it. The SSRS project continues to run and work correctly besides any data returned from the custom assembly. It actually won't even hit any break points that I set before reaching this. It seems to not be working at runtime, it builds fine. If I remove the instantiation the code seems to work properly. What could be causing this?

In the 1st screenshot the code runs perfectly fine. The breakpoint hits immediately.

But if I uncomment the code like in the 2nd screenshot the code does not work. It doesn't even hit the breakpoint set immediately before it. I'm not sure if it is crashing or not running at all. It does not give any errors in the debugger or event viewer (making me believe it isn't running at all).

1st screenshot
[image: 1st]

2nd screenshot
[image: 2nd]

Comment: Well, my magic 8 ball says you should surround the creation with a try/catch block, catch the exception and see what it says.

Comment: The code seems to crash right from the bat. It won't even hit any break points I set before it reaches the instatiation of dbContext.

Comment: Don't put try/catch block - that is useless. Better go to Windows Events and see what's new there about your application

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in event viewer. It seems whenever I try to do anything with dbContext it just crashes weather I instantiate a dbContext class or try to inherit from it (no instantiation). The SSRS project continues to run. It just seems to skip over all of the code in the custom assembly.

Comment: "The code seems to crash right from the bat." conflicts with the statement "It seems whenever I try to do anything with dbContext it just crashes weather I instantiate a dbContext class or try to inherit from it (no instantiation)". You're not being very clear here.

Comment: Sorry about that I'll try to be more clear. When I include the code to instantiate a dbContext class the code crashes or maybe it's not running at all I cannot tell. If I exclude the instantiation or comment it out the code works perfectly fine. I have a break point set at the entry point of my code and it's not being hit. So either the code is crashing immediately or it's not running at all.

Comment: I included some screenshot to try to explain better.

Comment: Are your connections configured in the configuration file?

Comment: Yes, in app.config. I tried using integrated security, and user id and password. No luck with either.